# Script that should remove certain txt files from a directory does not remove the files

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I am trying to write a python script that iterates over all the txt files in a directory and deletes those that have fewer words than a defined limit. The current script does not delete the files. Below is what I tried:

```
import os
wordLimit = 1000

def articleWordCount(filename):
    number = 0
    with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            number += len(words)
    return number

def articlesRemoval():
    directory = 'data'
    removedArticles =0
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     if filename.endswith(".txt"):
         if articleWordCount(filename) < wordLimit:
             removedArticles += 1
             os.remove(filename)
         else:
            print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    print(removedArticles)
articlesRemoval()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file in reading mode with the option `"r+"`, you are opening it in write mode and the function `articleWordCount` always returns 0.

Comment: And also make sure to pass the right path to `os.remove` as explained by Flash Thunder in his answer (and as already done by you, but only in the print function lol.)

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir()` doesn't return paths, only filenames, so the files that you are trying to remove do not exist... I am assuming that data is in the directory where you are starting the script and that it does find the files you want. Change `os.remove(filename)` to `os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))`:

```
import os
wordLimit = 1000

def articleWordCount(filename):
    number = 0
    with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            number += len(words)
    return number

def articlesRemoval():
    directory = 'data'
    removedArticles = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     if filename.endswith(".txt"):
         if articleWordCount(filename) < wordLimit:
             removedArticles += 1
             os.remove(os.path.join(directory, filename))
         else:
            print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    print(removedArticles)

articlesRemoval()
```